# Use existing Lambda layer(AWS) in Serverless(framework) project

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am migrating existing lambda functions created using the AWS GUI to a serverless framework project for better version control.

Few functions have layers, now I am trying to add the layer in the config file by directly using the ARN of the layer. This layer was created using the GUI, not using the framework.

```yaml
functions:
   functionName:
      handler: handlerFile.handler
      layers:
         - arn:aws:lambda:...:...:layer:layername:version # Using the ARN directly here, no layer config present in this project
```

Now when I try to deploy the project, I am getting `Module not found. Can't resolve 'sharp'`, so the layer is not working and unable to access the modules, the sharp library is in the layer. `node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory` **All the online tutorials and documentation add the layer files manually in the project and deploy a new layer and then use that, is it not possible to use the ARN of an existing layer?** It is happening at the webpack compilation step of deployment. This is the webpack config file

```js
module.exports = {
    target : 'node',
    mode: 'none'
}
```

The layer uses the folder structure mentioned in the docs, it also works fine in the existing lambda function that I created in the GUI. I am using multiple layers, so I didn't want to add the layer files in the serverless project to keep it clean. The last thing to try would be to manually create layer directories and deploy the layers first using the serverless framework and then it might work(though not sure)

**Is it possible to use the ARN of an existing layer directly in the serverless function config given that the layers have already been created using the GUI and not using the framework?**

```
Serverless framework version : 3
Layer type: nodejs 16
```

Comment: You should be able to look in the AWS Lambda web console, at the configuration of the function that was deployed, to see if the Layer is being correctly included in the function or not. You should do that to verify if the layer is being included or not before assuming that is the problem.

Comment: @MarkB I am getting this while deploying the function, it's stopping the function to deploy so I have nothing to check on the console. I believe `sls deploy` also has some compile step before finally deploying.

Comment: I don't understand how that error would be thrown at any time other than when actually running your code. If that is happening during deployment, instead of at run time, then perhaps you need to provide more details of your deployment logs so we have more context to understand the issue.

Comment: @MarkB yeah it is happening during deployment, It is during the webpack compilation step. Maybe webpack is causing issues as I am using the plugin. It's invoking the function before deploying, but it is not pulling the lambda layer from AWS so it does not have the module. I tried logging the directory structure during invocation locally and don't see modules anywhere, as many seem to point that it should be in the `opt` folder, but it's empty

Comment: I missed that you were doing a compile/transpile step. There is absolutely **NO WAY** for Webpack to have any knowledge of that lambda layer, much less for it to know what dependencies are provided by that layer. The Serverless framework isn't going to magically make that work in Webpack. You will have to add some settings to  your Webpack config for it to treat `sharp` as a "provided" library. If you were building your previous version of the Lambda function with Webpack, how did you not encounter the same issue then?

Comment: @MarkB I am using the serverless framework for the first time so there are no previous versions, before this, I was using the AWS GUI to create all the functions but soon realized that this way is not manageable and has limited version control. I thought using the serverless framework would be straightforward but there are multiple caveats here as well like the one on this question. Thanks for pointing out the possible webpack issue, I am trying few modifications with webpack to work it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use existing layers exactly in the way you added them, you should be able to use both existing layers via ARN and ones created by the Framework. Could you please share the full error and tell us what version of the Framework are you using?

On the side note - `module not found` might suggest that handler cannot be found. I see you have `hanlerFile` in config instead of (probably) `handlerFile`. Maybe this typo is causing the problem here?

Comment: That `hanlerFile` is a typo in the question, not in the code(have edited that). The layer has the `sharp` library, and I am using that in the handler. So the full error says `Can't resolve 'sharp'`. This is why I believe that the error is because it's unable to use the layer or access the node_modules in the layer.